# Not the same data between Android app and uitests

Tags: class, variables, static, xamarin.android, uitest

I have a project uitest and a project xamarin.android.
The project uitest use and is configured with the .apk which I generated from my project Android.

I call well this code before my test :

```
    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest() {
        app = ConfigureApp
            .Android
            .ApkFile("../../../MyProject.Droid/bin/Release/net.myProject.apk")
            .StartApp();
    }
```

My problem : I need to initialize some data which are statics but the MyClass.Statics of my project uitest and android are not the same ....

Thank you in advance !